# How can I manually build message in ink-e2e test?

Tags: ink, testing, call, e2e

I would like to manually build a message and send it in my ink-e2e test.
I'd like to construct and pass a selector and call data by myself.
How can I do it using ink 5.0.0-rc and ink-e2e 5.0.0-rc?